# In Laravel, it seems the middleware is not applied immediately

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 9.

I have this route, included in a group and middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'ensureUserIsAdmin'])->group(function () {
    .....
    Route::resource('sports', SportController::class);
    .....
});
```

The middleware is only to check if the user is or not an administrator.

When the connected user is not admin, and tries to go to this route for a **known** sport:

```
/sports/FOOT/edit
```

then he receives the response "FORBIDDEN". Perfect, the middleware made his job.

But when the same not admin user tries to go to a route for an **unknown** sport:

```
/sports/UNKNOWSPORT/edit
```

then he receives the response "NOT FOUND".  Is it normal? It looks like the framework makes a database request and only after he applies the middleware.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every route within `web.php` file is processed by `web` group middleware - you may find this in `RouteServiceProvider` class

```php
Route::middleware('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

This group defined within `Kernel` class and contains some app middleware. They're handled before any route specific middleware fires

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

So when you think your route has 'auth', 'ensureUserIsAdmin' as middleware only it is not quite true

In your case `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware is the one is failing and showing `404`. And yes, it makes query to database if there are some route parameters in it

For simplicity, let say you have this route and only model with id=1 exists

```php
Route::get('/sports/{sport}', function (Sport $sport) {
    dump($sport);
});
```

`/sports/1` is dumping model, `sports/2` shows `404` as expected. Let's comment `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class`

Now both pages are actually dumping model, but `sports/2` shows empty default model with no parameters

If you need to change this logic and show `403` for non-existing models, you may add middleware to a group **BEFORE** `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware

For example, lets' create simple middleware which always return `403` like

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    abort(403);
}
```

And change `web` group to

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        AlwaysFalse::class, // HERE I AM
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Now no matter what both pages will show `403`

But this will be applied for **EVERY** route within `routes/web.php` file, so you may change the logic like

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    // Applied only in any route named `sports.something` - resource routes including
    // is_admin() function doesn't really exists, middleware logic is up to you
    abort_if((Route::is('sports.*') && !is_admin()), 403);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now for admin user `/sports/1` shows model, `/sports/2` - `404` response.
For non-admin user both pages will return `403`.

About is it normal or not - I think yes. Ask yourself - what can you do (what your access level) over a thing which is doesn't even exists? So it better define first does model really exists and after you're sure it is, make something with it. But it is just my opinion, someone may disagree

Hope it'll help

Comment: This is an exceptional answer. thanks Ihar for the explanation.